# Geofence and startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges not responding under Do not disturb mode

Tags: core-location, geofencing, ios15, do-not-disturb

I am testing with location sensitive app that could not get response from neither Geofence nor startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges under DND mode while the app was killed. For example, no response was received while entering the registered region. I was testing with iPhone 11, iOS 15.0. Dose anyone have the same issue?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Im facing the same issue, on previous ios version It used to work fine, right after the ios 14 Im facing the issue that the app doesnt receive Geofence events.